# Notice: undefined variabl

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I'm trying to print out data from my database. It's doing it all well when there is something in the database but when it's empty it sends a notice that the variable is empty. How can I catch up this notice when my array is empty?

This is the notice: Notice: Undefined variable: result_array

PHP:

```
 $event = new Event();
    $event_id = $_GET['event_id'];
    $eventcomment = new EventComment();
    $comments = $eventcomment->GetAllComments($event_id);

<?php
                if(isset($comments))
                foreach ($comments as $comment) {


                        echo "<p> " .  $comment['tblevent_comment_text']. " <br>" . $comment['tblevent_comment_name'] . "</a></p>"; 

                }

                ?>
```

FUNCTION:

```
public function GetAllComments($event_id)
    {
            $db = new Db();

        $select = "SELECT * FROM tblevent_comment WHERE tblevent_id =" . $event_id . " ORDER BY tblevent_comment_id DESC";
        $result = $db->conn->query($select);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            $result_array[]=$row;  

        }

        return $result_array;
    }
```

Comment: just define the $result_array in GetAllComments function before using it.

Comment: Does a call to `empty()` works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `$result_array=array()` outside the `while loop` and then use inside the loop

```
$result_array=array()
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

            $result_array[]=$row;  

        }
```